# Convergence of $\sum2^{-\sqrt{k}} $

Tags: analysis

So I am going to determine whether this series converges or not:
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^{-\sqrt{k}} $$

Since this chapter is about the ratio test, I applied that test to this series.
I end up with this limit $$\lim_{k \to \infty} 2^{\sqrt{k}-\sqrt{k+1}}$$

I'm stuck here, don't know how to calculate this limit. I could simplify to: $$\sqrt{k}-\sqrt{k+1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k+1}} $$
But I doubt this will help me.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: $a^{1/n}\to 1$ as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: Okay so the ratio test doesn't work then? Which test could I use then?

Comment: ratio and root test are inconclusive. You will need to compare

Comment: Okay, do you have any hint on what I can compare it to?

Comment: @fejz1234 I have answered. Although I really like the integral test if you are familiar with it; I didn't see it

Answer (score 7):

The integral test works. We calculate \begin{align*} \int^\infty_0 2^{-\sqrt x} &= \int^\infty_0 e^{-\sqrt{x}\log 2} dx \\
&= \frac{ 2 }{(\log 2)^2}\int^\infty_0 te^{-t} dt \,\,\,\,\,\,\, [t = \sqrt x \log 2].
\end{align*} The latter converges (easily shown via integration by parts) so the sum converges as well.

EDIT: As suggested in the above comments, a comparison should work as well. For sufficiently large $k$, we see $\sqrt{k} \ge 2\log_2 k$. This follows since asymptotically $\sqrt{k} \gg \log_2 k$. For such $k$, we have $$2^{-\sqrt k} \le 2^{-2\log_2 k} = \frac 1 {k^2}.$$

Comment: This is really the simplest way, for sure.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Does mine not work? I do really like this solution

Comment: @qbert. For sure, it works !

Comment: I didnt really follow on the the integral-step. After the third equality, you seem to break out 2(log2)^2 and whats inside the integral seems to have changed?

Comment: Could anyone help me with this step:
$$ \int^\infty_0 e^{-\sqrt{x}\log 2} dx $$
$$= 2 (\log 2)^2\int^\infty_0 \sqrt{x}\cdot{log2}\cdot{e^{-\sqrt{x}\cdot{log2}}} dx$$
I cant see how this holds.

Comment: Just make the substitution: $t = \sqrt x \log 2$ gives $$dt =\frac {dx}{2\sqrt x} \log 2 = \frac{dx}{2\frac t {\log2}} \log2$$ so $$dx = \frac {2t}{(\log 2)^2}dt$$ so it seems I made a minor mistake with the constant (I'll edit). The rest is fine. You can't just replace the $t$ in that line with $\sqrt x\log 2$ because you also need to replace the $dt$.

Comment: Thanks very much! Got it now.

Comment: Integral test, great. But for heaven's sake don't say that the sum is _equal to_ the integral...

Comment: Agreed. As a calculus TA, I saw that all too often.

Answer (score 5):

It is not difficult to prove, if $k
 $ is sufficiently large, $k\geq K
 $ say, that $$\sqrt{2^{k}}\geq2k
 $$so if we use the [Cauchy condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) we note that $$\sum_{k\geq K}\frac{2^{k}}{2^{\sqrt{2^{k}}}}\leq\sum_{k\geq K}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k}$$ and so we can conclude that the series converges.

Comment: Why the downvote???

Comment: Welcome to the club of the victims of mysterious and unexplained downvotes !

Answer (score 3):

Let's compare with a series you probably know converges $\sum 1/n^2$. 
$$
L=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{2^{-\sqrt{n}}}{1/n^2}=
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{n^2}{2^{\sqrt{n}}}
$$
Since this is hard to look at, take $t=\sqrt{n}$, then 
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}\frac{t^4}{2^{t}}=
0
$$
By l'hospital's a few times, or just knowing that exponential growth beats polynomial growth for any degree polynomial. So your series converges by comparison to $\sum 1/n^2$

Comment: Okay thanks, this makes sense.

Comment: @fejz1234 No problem!

Comment: Im trying to understand the solution with the comparision of the integral (the other one). And im a bit confused. The third equality doesn't makes sense to me. Maybe you could help me out?

Comment: sure. Which inequality are you referring to? the third in the body of the text?

Comment: Obs. I mean the second equality. When he goes from the integral of $$ e^{-\sqrt{x}\cdot{ln2}} $$ to where he breaks out 2(ln2)^2 and changes whats inside the integral.

Comment: @fejz1234 he performed the substitution in brackets

Comment: Yeah, but even if i replace t with the original substitution .. I cant seem to follow how that equality is true.

Comment: This is what I mean :
$$ \int^\infty_0 e^{-\sqrt{x}\log 2} dx $$
$$= 2 (\log 2)^2\int^\infty_0 \sqrt{x}\cdot{log2}\cdot{e^{-\sqrt{x}\cdot{log2}}} dx$$

I have problems seeing how this is true

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44866/discussion-between-qbert-and-fejz1234).

Answer (score 2):

*Since @User8128 gave the solution using the integral test (probably the simplest for this problem), let me give another way.*

For the case where the ratio test is inconclusive as here $$u_k=2^{-\sqrt{k}}\implies \frac {u_{k+1}}{u_k}=2^{\sqrt{k}-\sqrt{k+1}}=1-\frac{\log (2)}{2} \frac 1 {\sqrt{k}} +O\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)$$ [Raabe's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#Raabe.27s_test) is very convenient.

Considering  $$R=k \left(\frac {u_k}{u_{k+1}} -1\right)=k\left(2^{\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}}-1\right)$$ and expanding again for large values of $k$, you will find $$R=\frac{\log ^2(2)}{8}+\frac{\log (2)}{2} \sqrt{k} +O\left(\frac{1}{k^{1/2}}\right)$$ So $R>1$ then the series will be absolutely convergent.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: @zarathustra seconded. There are two! What could possibly be wrong with this solution. My only hunch is that it is perceived as too complex, but so what, it is exposing OP (and me) to tools they may not know

Comment: @qbert. I am surprised by the fact that Raabe's test is not often used. I wonder if it is teached or not. May I ask for your opinion ?

Answer (score -1):

Hint:

$$\lim\limits_{k \to \infty} 2^{\sqrt{k} -\sqrt{k+1}} = 2^{\lim\limits_{k \to \infty} \sqrt{k} -\sqrt{k+1}}$$

Can you finish from here?

Comment: might be worth mentioning why this is true

Comment: Ah okay, so the limit will tend to 1. But then the ratio test doesn't provide with any information right? Which test could I use else to determine wheter it converges or not?
Edit: Yeah I would like to know why its true :P

Comment: it is true by continuity of exponentiation. Remember that limits and continuous functions commute. I actually don't think this is an answer to your question

Comment: It's not an answer to the main question no.

Comment: how was OP supposed to finish from here?

Comment: He wasn't able to solve the limit.